# Using a constant to store column names in the controller for stored parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

*QUESTION:* Are there any security risks or other issues with this implementation? The reason I'm doing this is because I don't want to type `f.text_field :field_name` for each form input. This seemed like the most DRY approach. **Main concern**: is that constants aren't enforced and wondering if this implementation poises a security risk?

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @fields = USER_FIELDS
  end

  def create
    render text: params.inspect
  end

  private
  USER_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "password"]
  def require_parmas
    params.require(:user).permit(USER_FIELDS)
  end
end
```

User#new `view`

```
<%= form_for @user, url: {action: :create} do |f| %>
  <% @fields.map do |field| %>
    <li>
      <%= f.label field %>

    <% if field =~ /password/ %>
      <%= f.password_field field %>
    </li>

    <% else %>
      <%= f.text_field field %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Create Your Account" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to freeze your constant so that it's impossible for any other code to change the value. This should satisfy your security concerns.

```
USER_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "password"].freeze
```

Otherwise, this is a fair approach. The only thing I'd do different is I'd move the `USER_FIELDS` constant to the *User* model since this is more in the "business logic" domain. And then just go ahead and access the constant directly instead of storing it in the `@fields` instance variable first. (Also, don't mark the constant as private if you take this approach or you won't be able to access it.)

```
<% User::USER_FIELDS.each do |field| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: In the same fashion from the controller: `params.require(:user).permit(User::USER_FIELDS)`

Comment: Yeah thats what I did. Thanks... Just felt iffy about putting the strong params array in the model (felt backwards).. But yeah adjusted to it... Thanks.. Wondering if it just adds complexity unnecessarily..

Comment: There's likely a "business" reason why these 4 fields are grouped together. So you may find a reason to reuse this grouping later in the model or another controller or view. In which case, you shouldn't be calling UsersController::USER_FIELDS, because that's a little silly. Maybe that perspective helps. Cheers.

Comment: You think with using `freeze` I should write a rescue block incase something/someone tries to modify the constant?

Comment: The exception that would be thrown if some code tries to modify a frozen constant would happen at the time of reassignment. So that should be self-discoverable at code time. So don't worry about exception handling :)